# Can't use \dotsb & \dotsm when load MdSymbol

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts

MWE:

````
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[papersize={10cm,5cm}, text={9cm,4cm}]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}   {OT1}{cmsmf} {m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{cmssm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}     {OMS}{cmsssy}{m}{n}
\usepackage{mdsymbol}
%   OR  \usepackage[onlymath]{MyriadPro} % need ```FontPro```
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 & \iint\dotsi\int \log( f_1 f_2 \dotsm f_k ) \diff\mu \\
=& \dotso\cdots\dotsc \\  %%%    ↑↑↑↑↑↑   ↓↓↓↓↓↓
=& \iint\dotsi\int (\log f_1 + \log f_2 + \dotsb +\log f_k) \diff\mu.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
````

get messages

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\dotsm ->\protect \cdots
\dotsb ->\protect \cdots
```

and `\dotsi` & `\dotso` output normally.

If I want to use `\dotsb` & `\dotsm`, does it have to be implemented through applying `\cdots`?

Also, when I use `MyriadPro` from `FontPro`, the same situation occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mdsymbol` redefines `\cdots` in a way that's unexpected by `amsmath`.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\LetLtxMacro{\cdotsams}{\cdots}
\usepackage{mdsymbol}
\makeatletter\let\@cdots\cdots\makeatother
\LetLtxMacro{\cdots}{\cdotsams}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}   {OT1}{cmsmf} {m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{cmssm} {m}{it}
%\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}     {OMS}{cmsssy}{m}{n} %<--- not if you use mdsymbol

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   & \iint\dotsi\int \log( f_1 f_2 \dotsm f_k ) \diff\mu \\
={}& \dotso\cdots\dotsc \\  %%%    ↑↑↑↑↑↑   ↓↓↓↓↓↓
={}& \iint\dotsi\int (\log f_1 + \log f_2 + \dotsb +\log f_k) \diff\mu.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

*Don't* change the `symbols` math font along with `mdsymbol`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answers and suggestions about settings. I feel the gap between the sides of ```\dotsm``` is too narrow, but when I use ```fdsymbol``` to replace ```mdsymbol```, see the same narrow spacing. I believe this is the perfect solution